# Is it possible to set the border to be the default Excel faint grey using StyleFrame?

Tags: python, styleframe

Looking at the [documentation](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_documentation.html#utils-borders) for StyleFrame, it looks like none of the borders options are just the normal faint grey border found by default on Excel spreadsheets.

Is it possible to set this using `Styler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame/issues/42) this requires a bit of a workaround. Set both `border_type` and `fill_pattern_type` to `None`.

```
Styler(border_type=None, fill_pattern_type=None)
```