# How to remove the border of Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, border, styleframe

When I use pandas dataframe to excel, the border of the header will be generated automatically. When I use styleframe to excel, the border of the whole table will be generated automatically. 
I can not use pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None to remove the border of dataframe and styleframe.

pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

Comment: Try creating the StyleFrame object with the following default style: `sf = StyleFrame(..., Styler(border_type=None, fill_pattern_type=None))` this will mimic the "default" Excel borders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set the border to be the default Excel faint grey using StyleFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487186/is-it-possible-to-set-the-border-to-be-the-default-excel-faint-grey-using-stylef)

Comment: I also want to know how to remove the border of Pandas dataframe, not just styleframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import pandas.io.formats.style

pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style= None
```